# My wordpress website does not show categories and tags in admin

Tags: wordpress, backend

Categories exist but are not showing up in wordpress backend.

Please help.

Comment: you are using custom post? or WPML? or some other plugin? Any more details will help us understand question

Comment: No, it is the default post type.

Comment: tried disabling all plugins?

Comment: Disabled all the plugins but no effect.

Comment: I don't think we are getting all the info needed for this question.

Comment: Hi Daniel

What more info you need on this issue

Comment: Please check this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39933074/category-error.png

Comment: trying turning on WP_DEBUG and check if it gives some error

Comment: Turning on WP_DEBUG throws 3 errors when I try to access the backend

Notice: load_plugin_textdomain was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.7 with no alternative available. in /home/freepres/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2927

Notice: Constant WP_MEMORY_LIMIT already defined in /home/freepres/public_html/wp-config.php on line 94

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/freepres/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:2841) in /home/freepres/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 876

Comment: @boom_Shiva Please check the error log.

Comment: nothing serious I guess, you can give me access in chat, in case you need help

Comment: database was properly migrated, you sure about it, just try importing it again

Comment: @boom_Shiva Thanks for letting me know.
I migrated db via ssh terminal and it worked fine for a couple of days, later on this problem occurred and now it is not possible for me to migrate the db as the client has added n number of stories.